# Calling a Swift function from C++

Tags: c++, ios, swift

I was wondering if it's possible to call a Swift function from C++? And if YES, how? I know that we can call a C++ function from Swift but I haven't found an exact answer about this.

Comment: Do you want to know if it can be done or _how_ to do it?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious probably both.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will illicit simple yes or no answers which in this case are not beneficial to the community.

Comment: Ok... If it's just boolean issue... Why nobody gave the right response (YES or NO ) until now? I think it's a good opportunity to learn a bit more.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I just edited the question.

Comment: I'm also seeking for an answer on this one, do anyone already has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

While there’s no official way to call a Swift function directly from C, you can set up a function pointer that’s callable from C. Whether that helps you depends on your exact circumstances. For example, on Apple platforms it’s super useful for integrating with C APIs that use C callbacks (things like CFRunLoop observers).

Pasted in a below is an example sans anything Apple-ish.

Share and Enjoy
—
Quinn “The Eskimo!”
Apple Developer Relations, Developer Technical Support, Core OS/Hardware
let myEmail = "eskimo" + "1" + "@apple.com"

```
// main.swift

private func printGreeting(modifier: UnsafePointer<CChar>) {
    print("Hello \(String(cString: modifier))World!")
}

var callbacks = SomeCLibCallbacks(
    printGreeting: { (modifier) in
        printGreeting(modifier: modifier)
    }
)
SomeCLibSetup(&callbacks)

SomeCLibTest()

// SomeCLib.h

#ifndef SomeCLib_h
#define SomeCLib_h

struct SomeCLibCallbacks {
    void (* _Nonnull printGreeting)(const char * _Nonnull modifier);
};
typedef struct SomeCLibCallbacks SomeCLibCallbacks;

extern void SomeCLibSetup(const SomeCLibCallbacks * _Nonnull callbacks);

extern void SomeCLibTest(void);

#endif

// SomeCLib.c

#include "SomeCLib.h"

static SomeCLibCallbacks sCallbacks;

extern void SomeCLibSetup(const SomeCLibCallbacks * callbacks) {
    sCallbacks = *callbacks;
}

extern void SomeCLibTest(void) {
    sCallbacks.printGreeting("Cruel ");
}
```

Source: https://forums.swift.org/t/best-way-to-call-a-swift-function-from-c/9829/2